# How to use chomp

Tags: arrays, perl, chomp

Below I have a list of data I am trying to manipulate.  I want to split the columns and rejoin them in a different arrangement.

I would like to switch the last element of the array with the third one but I'm running into a problem.
Since the last element of the array contains a line character at the end, when I switch it to be a thrid, it kicks everything a line down.

**CODE**

```
while (<>) {
    my @flds = split /,/;
    DO STUFF HERE;
    ETC;
    print join ",", @flds[ 0, 1, 3, 2 ];    # switches 3rd element with last
}
```

**SAMPLE DATA**

```
1,josh,Hello,Company_name
1,josh,Hello,Company_name
1,josh,Hello,Company_name
1,josh,Hello,Company_name
1,josh,Hello,Company_name
1,josh,Hello,Company_name
```

---

**MY RESULTS** - Kicked down a line.

```
1,josh,Company_name
,Hello1,josh,Company_name
,Hello1,josh,Company_name
,Hello1,josh,Company_name
,Hello1,josh,Company_name
,Hello1,josh,Company_name,Hello
```

---

*Desired REsults**

```
1,josh,Company_name,Hello
1,josh,Company_name,Hello
1,josh,Company_name,Hello
1,josh,Company_name,Hello
1,josh,Company_name,Hello
1,josh,Company_name,Hello
```

---

I know it has something to do with chomp but when I chomp the first or last element, all \n are removed.
When I use chomp on anything in between, nothing happens.  Can anyone help?

Comment: If your system has `perldoc`, I'd recommend using it first when you have a question about a particular function. It's quite convenient to just run from your shell and the documentation is really good. Run like this: `perldoc -f <function>` or in this case, [`perldoc -f chomp`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) (I've also added a link to the online version). Note that the documentation for `chomp` contains a code example that looks very much like your code.

Comment: Very cool!  Thanks much for the tip, I find myself needing hard examples for functions a lot of the time! @ThisSuitIsBlackNot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`chomp` removes the trailing newline from the argument. Since none of your four fields should *actually* contain a newline, this is probably something you want to do for the purposes of data processing. You can remove the newline with `chomp` before you even split the line into fields, and then add a newline after each record with your final print statement:

```
while (<>) {
    chomp; # Automatically operates on $_
    my @flds = split /,/;
    DO STUFF HERE;
    ETC;
    print join(",", @flds[0,1,3,2]) . "\n"; # switches 3rd element with last
}
```

Comment: or `say join ",", @flds[0,1,3,2];`

Answer (score 0):

```
while ( <> ) {
    chomp; 
    my @flds = split /,/;
       ... rest of your stuff
 }
```

In the `while` loop, as each line is processed, `$_` is set to the contents of the line. `chomp` by default, acts on `$_` and removes trailing line feeds. `split` also defaults to using `$_`, so that works fine.

Technically what will be happening is the last element in `@flds` includes the trailing `\n` from the line - e.g. `$flds[3]`.

Answer (score 0):

The chomp() function will remove (usually) any newline character from the end of a string. The reason we say usually is that it actually removes any character that matches the current value of $/ (the input record separator), and $/ defaults to a newline.

Example 1. Chomping a string
Most often you will use chomp() when reading data from a file or from a user. When reading user input from the standard input stream (STDIN) for instance, you get a newline character with each line of data. chomp() is really useful in this case because you do not need to write a regular expression and you do not need to worry about it removing needed characters.

```
while (my $text = <STDIN>) {
chomp($text);
print "You entered '$text'\n";
last if ($text eq '');
```

}

Example usage and output of this program is:

a word
  You entered 'a word'
  some text
  You entered 'some text'

You entered ''